# Hide the side menu bar using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide the side left menu bar on click of button as well as on click of any where in the document.

I tried the following code which is in the below link.

I need some help.....

Here is the tried code:
Jquery:

```
$("#openMenuLayout").click(function(e){
   debugger;
    if ($('#menuLayout').hasClass('open-menu')){
       $('#menuLayout').removeClass('open-menu');
       $('#openMenuLayout').find('img').removeClass().addClass('opened_icon');
          $(this).css('display','block');
     } else {
       $('#menuLayout').addClass('open-menu');
       $('#openMenuLayout').find('img').removeClass().addClass('open-menu_icon');
       $(this).css('display','block');
     }

     e.preventDefault();
 });
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/WDqZ2/1/)

Comment: "as well as on click of any where in the document." do you mean anywhere except the sidebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will close the menu when the user clicks outside of the menu.

```
$(document).click(function(e){

    if (!$("#menuLayout").is(e.target) && $("#menuLayout").has(e.target).length === 0) { 

           // Clicked outside, close menu
            $("#menuLayout").removeClass('open-menu');

    }

});
```

Comment: @itay no specific reason. Would it be better with `click`?

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to this question: [Opening mobile menu in Chrome for Android by setting width only works first time.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645509/jquery-bind-click-to-open-menu-only-works-first-time-on-mobile/21649519)

That's my solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jiyHI

Basically you create a layer between your menu and the content, which is clickable.

**EDIT:** The code

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="menu-button"></div>
<div id="menu">
     <!--your menu-->    
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

CSS

```
#content {
  ...
  z-index:1;
}

#overlay{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  z-index:5;  //between content and overlay
  display: none;
}

#menu{
     z-index:10; //greater than content and overlay
 }
```

Javascript

```
$("#menu-button").bind( "click", function() {
  $('#menu').toggleClass('open');
  $('#overlay').show(0);
});

$("#overlay").bind( "click", function() {
  $('#mobile-menu').removeClass('open');
  $('#overlay').hide(0);     
});
```

Comment: link-only answers are discouraged.. also with similar or duplicate questions you should flag. Try to sum up the main points of the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

To close the side bar when you click anywhere in the the document you need to put the logic in the below function.

$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
});

Answer (score 0):

This allows you toggle visibility with image also!

```
$("#openMenuLayout").click(function(e){
        if ($('#menuLayout').hasClass('open-menu')){
            $('#menuLayout').removeClass('open-menu');
            $('#openMenuLayout').find('img').removeClass().addClass('opened_icon');
            $(this).css('display','block');
        } else {
            $('#menuLayout').addClass('open-menu');
            $('#openMenuLayout').find('img').removeClass().addClass('open-menu_icon');
            $(this).css('display','block');
        }  
        e.preventDefault();
 });


$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("nav#menuLayoutList");
    console.log(e.target.nodeName);
    if (!container.is(e.target) 
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0 
        && e.target.nodeName != "IMG")
    {
        $('#menuLayout').removeClass('open-menu');
    } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WDqZ2/8/

Comment: or you can add e.target.id != 'something' instead of e.target.nodeName != "IMG" . This would be better approach.